# Game slows down while pressing a key or moving mouse

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, mouse, sdl

Recently I've been trying to write my own game (clone of Space Invaders) using SDL but I had a problem with events...
I have 2 events, one is emited by my timer, I use it to draw moving enemy ships. Second event is my keyboard event which I use to move my ship. 
When I start the game, enemy ships start to move exactly as I expect but if I press key or move mouse, they move slower. I have same problem while moving my ship, if I try to move mouse, frame rate slows down a lot.
My event loop:

```
while(!exit)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event));
    {
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) exit=true;
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym) 
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                pship.move(pship.getPosition().x - 1, pship.getPosition().y);
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                pship.move(pship.getPosition().x + 1, pship.getPosition().y);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_USEREVENT)
        {
            switch(event.user.code)
            {
            case 1:
                static int xOffset, yOffset;
                xOffset++;
                yOffset++;

                drawEnemyShips(eship,xOffset,yOffset);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Visual c++ 2010 express and SDL 1.2.15

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event));
```

You definitely don't want that `;` on there! The way you have it, you are eating events. If you get an event, `SDL_PollEvent` returns one, so you call `SDL_PollEvent` again. If there's no event, you break out of the `while` loop and process it. But if there's a second event, you never process the first.

But in any event, a spinning poll loop is broken. It's like the kid who keeps asking "Are we there yet" every minute and doesn't let the parents drive. Use `SDL_WaitEvent` to wait for an event rather than spinning the CPU polling for one.

A simple way to do it is to change:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&event));
```

to this:

```
while (SDL_WaitEvent(&event) != 0)
```

That will leave your code a bit clumsy (the `while` loop is still needless, when you break out of it, you just re-enter it), but at least it will not be broken.

Comment: How is it possible that I didnt't get error or at least warning? Works just fine... Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing illegal about an empty `while` loop, nor is there anything wrong with using braces to create an unconditional scope.

Comment: @norbert108: turn on `-Wempty-body` and the compiler will warn you when you put a `;` right after a `for ()` or `while ()` construct.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: And then to avoid the warning where you shouldn't get it, you can use something like `{ ; }` as an empty body. (Or `{ }`, or a macro like `nothing()` that expands to an empty body.)

Comment: "Use SDL_WaitEvent to wait for an event rather than spinning the CPU polling for one." -- sorry, but this is awful advice. If you look at [the SDL source code](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/c31b24c7babc/src/events/SDL_events.c#420) you'll see that `SDL_WaitEvent()` just calls `SDL_PollEvent()` in an  infinite loop itself, except that it sleeps the calling thread for 10ms between each call, which is pretty terrible.

Comment: @TristanBrindle If there exists a function that is documented to do exactly what you want to do, you should generally call it. You should able to rely on the implementation being sensible. If the implementation is not sensible, and this materially affects you, you may want to work around the implementation defect as an implementation/version-specific hack. But your starting point should be calling the function specified to do exactly what you want to do, if there is one.